# Adding an array to the end of another Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm very new to python and I have been faced with the task of taking several arrays into another array, this is inside of a loop.
So if you had

```
a = np.array([2,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,2,3,4])
```

and

```
b = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,2,23,2,3,3,3])
```

and

```
c = np.array([])
```

and wanted the result

```
c = [[2,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,2,3,4],
     [1,1,1,1,1,2,23,2,3,3,3]]
```

so if I did `c[0,:]` I would get `[2,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,2,3,4]`
I tried using `c = [c, np.array(a)]` then next iteration you get `c = [c, np.array(b)]`
but I i do `c[0,:]` i get the error message `list indices must be integers not tuples`

EDIT:

When I get it to print out `c` it gives `[array([2,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,2,3,4],dtype = unit8)]`

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I would *highly* recommend not doing this in a loop, especially for large arrays! Every time you concatenate two numpy arrays together, the result is a new copy of the array. Generating the copy becomes slower and slower as the array gets larger and larger on each loop iteration. If you must do your appending inside a loop then I suggest you use a regular Python list, and convert it to a numpy array outside the loop (unlike numpy arrays, you can append to Python lists in place without generating a copy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [10]: np.vstack((a,b))
Out[10]:
array([[ 2,  3,  4,  3,  4,  4,  5,  3,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2, 23,  2,  3,  3,  3]])
```

EDIT: Here's an example of using it in a loop to gradually build a matrix:

```
In [14]: c = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)

In [15]: c
Out[15]: array([9, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 1, 9, 2, 0])

In [16]: for _ in xrange(10):
   ....:     c = np.vstack((c, np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)))
   ....:

In [17]: c
Out[17]:
array([[9, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 1, 9, 2, 0],
       [0, 8, 1, 9, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 4, 2, 9, 6, 7, 1, 3, 2],
       [6, 0, 7, 9, 1, 9, 8, 5, 9, 8],
       [8, 1, 0, 9, 6, 6, 6, 4, 8, 5],
       [0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 9, 9, 4, 6, 9],
       [4, 0, 9, 8, 6, 0, 2, 2, 7, 0],
       [1, 3, 4, 8, 2, 2, 8, 7, 7, 7],
       [0, 0, 4, 8, 3, 6, 5, 6, 5, 7],
       [7, 1, 3, 8, 6, 0, 0, 3, 9, 0],
       [8, 5, 7, 4, 7, 2, 4, 8, 6, 7]])
```

Comment: Hi when I do this getting `array([[2],[1]])` instead of all of the elements

Comment: I'd recommend checking the code around it. `np.vstack` just vertically stacks the arrays you pass to it, and so something else in your code may be cutting off the rest of the results inadvertently.

Comment: what i'm trying to do add them to a 3rd array `c`

Comment: Added an edit to show an example of doing it in a loop. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks this is brilliant, a lot of help, and easy to follow

Comment: I think that `vstack` is the way to go. However, I assume that it will be significantly faster (and more pythonic) to do `rows = [np.random.randint(0, 10, 10) for _ in xrange(10)]` and then `c = np.vstack(rows)`, instead of building the numpy matrix gradually. (Well you can do in a single statement, but it will ultimately depend on the application)

Answer (score 3):

Most numpythonic way is using `np.array`:

```
>>> c = np.array((a,b))
>>> 
>>> c
array([[ 2,  3,  4,  3,  4,  4,  5,  3,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2, 23,  2,  3,  3,  3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
>>> c = [list(a), list(b)]
>>> c
[[2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 23, 2, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate arrays in `numpy`. For this to work, they must have the same size in all dimensions except the concatenation direction.

If you just say

```
>>> c = np.concatenate([a,b])
```

you will get

```
>>> c
array([ 2,  3,  4,  3,  4,  4,  5,  3,  2,  3,  4,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,
   23,  2,  3,  3,  3])
```

So in order to achieve what you want you first have to add another dimension to your vectors `a` and `b` like so

```
>>> a[None,:] 
array([[2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4]])
```

or equivalently

```
>>> a[np.newaxis,:]
array([[2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4]])
```

So you could do the following:

```
>>> c = np.concatenate([a[None,:],b[None,:]],axis = 0)
>>> c
array([[ 2,  3,  4,  3,  4,  4,  5,  3,  2,  3,  4],
   [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2, 23,  2,  3,  3,  3]])
```